# Center div having width: 350px in a responsive div container

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am trying to make responsive one of my sites... :)
In standard view (pc), I have a `div container` called `"article"` containing more divs on 2 cols, all of these have `width: 350px`.
Resizing the screen, I want the divs into `"article"` are centered into it in a single col.
I have tried a lot of ways, including `margin: 0` `auto, display: inline-block`, `display: table`, but does not works, and divs are always flotted to left of "article". :( 
**Using this method in media query:**

```css
left: 50%
margin-left: 175px;
```

It center the div when `"article"` has `width: 707px` (708 is just I need for divs on two cols including a few padding),
 but reducing width under `707px` value, the centering is losed because margin-left has a fixed value!

Comment: Please provide a more detailed snippet that reproduce the problem so it would be much easier to understand and help you.

Comment: For future, have a look into Twitter Bootstrap (v4) it has the flexibility to customise and it makes it easier for responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to `margin: 0 auto;` your div, like so:

```css
.container {background-color:red;}
.content {background-color:aqua;width: 350px;margin:10px auto;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eleifend eu leo quis euismod. Phasellus blandit suscipit ipsum non pretium. In facilisis scelerisque sodales. Integer posuere nunc eget orci tincidunt, et dapibus dui porta. Duis pellentesque commodo mi, non congue erat imperdiet ac. Morbi facilisis accumsan dapibus. Quisque metus risus, ullamcorper ut faucibus ac, elementum in arcu. Aliquam vulputate sapien sed ullamcorper dignissim. Cras aliquet nisl nibh, a feugiat tortor pellentesque ac. Donec id mollis ante, sit amet ultricies velit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by using percents on your sub columns. Fixed widths will cause unwanted problems.

Then on your mobile layout, have your sub column go full width and remove the float. That will have the columns stack on top of each other.

```
.article .subColumn {
    width:48%;
    float:left;
}
@media screen only and (max-width:480px) {
    .article subColumn {
        float:none;
        width:100%;
        padding:0 25px;
    }
}
```